# What is the correct order in which tables should be joined

Tags: oracle, join

I have three tables

TABLE 1
 **PLANS** -> Has all the plans information

COLUMNS:

- PLAN_ID
- PLAN_NAME
- OTHER_DETAILS

(PLAN_ID is the PRIMARY KEY)

TABLE 2
 **REGISTER** ->

COLUMNS:

- RUN_ID
- PLAN_ID
- REGISTER_DETAILS

  (RUN_ID AND PLAN_ID) is the primary key

  TABLE 3
  **ELECTION** ->
  Columns
- RUN_ID
- PLAN_ID
- ELECTION_DETAILS

  (`RUN_ID` AND `PLAN_ID`) is the primary key

`PLAN_ID` could be present in either `REGISTER` (or) `ELECTION` (or) BOTH tables.

For an input `RUN_ID` , I need to pick rows in the below format such that if a plan has only register details only `REGISTER_DETAILS` is picked.

If a plan has both `REGISTER_DETAILS` and `ELECTION_DETAILS` then both the details should get returned.

**Report Format**:

RUN_ID PLAN_ID REGISTER_DETAILS ELECTION_DETAILS

**Solution**

I tried by joining the tables in below format:

```
SELECT
 ..
 FROM 
 PLANS A

  LEFT JOIN REGISTER B

  ON (A.PLAN_ID = B.PLAN_ID

      AND B.RUN_ID = 'Input Run Id')

  LEFT JOIN ELECTION C

  ON (A.PLAN_ID = C.PLAN_ID

      AND C.RUN_ID = 'Input Run Id')
```

But this is also returning plans that are not present in `REGISTER` and `ELECTION` tables.

Can someone please tell what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
WHERE B.PLAN_ID IS NOT NULL OR
      C.PLAN_ID IS NOT NULL
```

to the end of your query.

Best of luck.

Comment: Does this not make the outer join redundant, turning the query into an inner join?

Comment: I don't think so. It's simply stating that after the OUTER JOINs are performed at least one of the outer-joined tables needs to have been there - but you can't code it as an INNER JOIN because you don't need to have both.

Comment: A plan could be present in either one of the tables (or) both the tables.